# Benq 5000 Scanner Not Working

Tags: documentation, scanner

My scanner is detected but its not working Scanner BENQ 5000

> lsusb

```
root@onezero:/home/one# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 093a:2700 Pixart Imaging, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 04a5:20f8 Acer Peripherals Inc. (now BenQ Corp.) Benq 5000
```

[image]
[image]

How do make it Work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it finally worked following these steps :

1. Download driver from [Benq](http://benq.eu/support/downloads/downloads.cfm?product=631) . I randomly choose the XP one 6.3.5000.1
2. Unzip and keep only the 20F8V119.bin file from the bin directory
3. Copy this file to the/usr/share/sane/snapscan/ directory of your computer
4. Sudo edit the /etc/sane.d/snapscan.conf file on top you will see one line like that

   ```
   firmware /usr/share/sane/snapscan/your-firmwarefile.bin
   ```

   change 'your-firmwarefile.bin' to be 20F8V119.bin then save.
5. As I play quite a lot of things at this step I had to restart my computer not so sure if needed or not.
6. Finally install and launch xsane scan my version is 0.998(simple scan do not work for me)

Et voilà ! 
Good luck

Comment: Please notice if I launch 'Simple scan' first it will lock the driver and then I must restart computer in order to have xsane to works well.

Comment: I have a Benq 5150C and it works but scans 1/4 of page.

Comment: firmware: command not found.... Any ideas why this issue?